# jquery ajax parsing xml without find

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, ajax

I am working on getting our webservices to use ajax in an attempt to speed up some pages. Below is a sample I have working, but I would like to make this easier to use across multiple pages with different webservices. Is there a way to parse through the XML without knowing the node names? So in my example below I do $(this).find('ID').text(), but what I want to be able to do is just find the first node and get its name dynamically and then be able to create my header row with the name and the value row with the values. 
I also want to do this without knowing how many columns and/or rows.

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:51558/Service1.asmx/GetData',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (xml) {
                var tbl = '<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th>Title</th></tr>';
                $(xml).find('SiteMessages ').each(function () {
                    tbl += '<tr><td>' + $(this).find('ID').text() + '</td>';
                    tbl += '<td>' + $(this).find('StartDate').text() + '</td>';
                    tbl += '<td>' + $(this).find('EndDate').text() + '</td>';
                    tbl += '<td>' + $(this).find('Title').text() + '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#datagrid').html(tbl + '</table>');
                alert('success');
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**I have looked at jquery.parseXML, but I cannot find any example where it does not use something like $title = $xml.find( "title" );

Comment: Does this help? http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XML DOM for navigate in nodes. See in http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp

Comment: I thought of this last night and started writing a recursive method to loop through all of the nodes and their children. I still have to use .find, but I can do it with something like $(this).find(this.nodeName).text(). That will at least give me some flexibility in how I handle the XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use JSON and send a schema array with each response

```
{"columns":["ID","StartDate","EndDate","Title"],
  "data" :[ [1, "12/12/2012", "1/1/2013","Manager"]]
}
```

Comment: Json seems to be the go to answer when someone talks about ajax, but in my case I am stuck with the XML. Thanks.

Comment: why stuck with xml? JSON is lighter in size and easier to work with and every server languagae has JSON support

Comment: I am stuck with XML because that is what will be returned from the real webservice. Ihave since found a function that will translate the XML to Json and I have my basic functions written to do what I wanted and only need to pass in the URL to the webservice.